# Error No.5 When Trying to Recursively Look Through Folders

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive file listing program in Python.
When I run the program without the exception catching code at the end, it returns error number 5,
saying that access is denied to some windows folders. I have admin privileges and everything, but it still keeps throwing me this error.
Is it at all possible to get around this and list the files in those directories?

```python
import os

def wrapperList():
    mainList = []
    fileList = os.listdir("C:")
    for file in fileList:
        path = os.path.join("C:\\", file)
        if (os.path.isdir(path)):
            mainList.append(recurList(path))
        else:
            mainList.append(path)
    print mainList
def recurList(directory):
    try:
        fileList = os.listdir(directory)
        tempList = []
        for file in fileList:
            path = os.path.join(directory, file)
            if (os.path.isdir(file)):
                tempList.append(recurList(path))
            else:
                tempList.append(file)
        return tempList
    except:
        return ["Access Denied"]

wrapperList()
```

Comment: Don't link to your code, post it, also post the exception you get. Edit: Fixed the code by putting it in your post, but you'll need to add the exception.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example where you would be much better off using [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) than trying to implement the same thing yourself.

E.g:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/some/path"):
    ...
```

As to the error, if you are getting permission denied, then it's probably that you really are denied access there. I'm not a windows user, so I don't know for sure, but do you need to run the program with admin privileges? (equivalent to running as root, or `sudo` under linux).

Comment: I know that there is an administrator command prompt in windows. I guess it depends how he is launching it. I also remember there being a Run As Admin right click option for launching it graphicly. With windows, who knows.

Comment: Definitely, `os.walk` is the way to go and "don't reinvent the wheel" is the best reason for that. +1